# lenovo thinkpad sl500 fn keys & hdd protection on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, thinkpad

(i use **ubuntu 10.04 64bit**)
i cant get most of my fn keys to work in this laptop. i especially need fn+f8, which switches between trackpoint & touchpad. what i tried:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

(added lenovo-sl-laptop to the file) then:

```
sudo modprobe lenovo-sl-laptop
```

this failed: `FATAL: Module lenovo_sl_laptop not found.`

as for the **hdapsd** i dont have it installed, since i dont know how to configure it (i guess it helps hdd protection).

Comment: I don't know anything about Linux on these, but FYI the hard drive active protection uses an accelerometer in the drive to lock the heads if it detects sudden movement (such as dropping the machine).